# Emacs' Preview LaTeX: Using different background colors depending on environment

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

In Emacs' Preview LaTeX, I would like included graphics (e.g., what's inside `\includegraphics`) to look different than all other previewed environments.  Otherwise, graphics that have black lines become unreadable in a black-background buffer.

I know that Preview LaTeX sets color replacements according to the variable `preview-reference-face`.  How can I dynamically change this variable depending on the environment being previewed?

Comment: How do you generate previews?  With `C-c C-p C-e` (`preview-environment`) or another function?  In the former case it shouldn't be difficult to get what you request.